# User input length wrong result in MIPS32

Tags: assembly, mips32

Ok so we have a simple program that takes an input(string) from the user,max length is 1000, and then it prints the length of that string.But for some reason,result is not the correct one.For example if I enter word  **name** i get result **5** , and if i enter word **example** i get **8** which of course is wrong.Can somebody tell me why is this happening?Here is my code:

```
.data
    buffer: .space 1000
    str1:  .asciiz "Enter string:"
    str2:  .asciiz "You wrote:\n"
    str3:  .asciiz "String length is: \n"
    CRLF: .asciiz "\n"

.text

main:
    la $a0, str1    # Load and print string asking for string
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    la $a0, CRLF
    li $v0, 4
    syscall #change line

    li $v0, 8       # take in input

    la $a0, buffer  # load byte space into address
    li $a1, 1000   # allot the byte space for string

    move $t0, $a0   # save string to t0
    syscall

    loop:
    lb $t1 0($t0)
    beq $t1 $zero end
    addi $t0 $t0 1
    j loop

    end:
    la $t1 buffer
    sub $t3 $t0 $t1 #$t3 now contains the length of the string

    la $a0, str3    # Load and print string about string length
    li $v0, 4
    syscall



    move $a0,$t3
    li $v0,1
    syscall

    la $a0, CRLF
    li $v0, 4
    syscall #change line


    li $v0, 10      # end program
    syscall
```

A small extra question.How can we change this code to make input max length change dynamically according to what the user enters?

Comment: Put a breakpoint after `syscall` for user input, and study the returned register values and buffer (memory) content. (and check the docs of `syscall, v0=8`). About extra question... I don't understand it. You have only "so much" free memory in computer, you can't store unlimited input. Your max 1000 chars is reasonable for input from user, but you may go for "all of the free memory" buffer, which would be totally impractical. But possible.

Comment: how do i put a breakpoint in MIPS32?? I googled a little bit but came up empty..

Comment: You didn't write what environment you are using. From the `syscall` usage I would guess it's one of SPIM/MARS emulators? They have built-in debugger.

Comment: i am using QtSpim simulator, but running the program step by step, really does not give me any help on why i get wrong result.. I am lost here..help me please

Comment: It should give you not only some help, but complete help. So I wonder how you are reading it. After executing `syscall` to read user input, and entering "name", if you will use memory window to monitor values in memory at address `buffer`, you should see bytes: `6E 61 6D 65 0D 00 ?? ?? ??` (?? are old values before `syscall`, the `0D` may be `0A` instead, depends what the SPIM OS does use as newline/enter char). If you will compare these with ASCII table, you will see that memory contains ASCII string "name" with enter/newline character after it, and then zero terminator.

Comment: Conclusion from that should be 1) keep toying around with the debugger to learn how take a look on any interesting value, be it register or memory. Also you should be able to set breakpoints by right click in memory window (citing some web tutorial, I never used QtSpim personally), and run up to them (to save time of stepping over code which you believe is correct). Programming in Assembly without debugger is extremely cumbersome and requires you to run the code in your head, that's much harder. 2) "name" produces result 5, because you count also the "enter" char.

Comment: BTW, I read about breakpoint here: http://ecs-network.serv.pacific.edu/ecpe-170/tutorials/qtspim-tutorial  (unfortunately this tutorial looks OK for me, as I have already experience from other platforms, but it may be too short for somebody new to Assembly). Keep searching, also official documentation to MIPS CPU, or SPIM should be your first class citizen. The official documentation is usually more correct than Internet, as some people tend to write tutorials even if they lack knowledge themselves. :D